# Do Postgres JSONB key lengths matter for disk space?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

With the Postgres JSON column it just stores the JSON, so the same JSON values but with longer key names will take up more disk space.  Is this also the case for JSONB columns, or does the binary abstraction sidestep this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no size advantage to JSONB columns with duplicate keys across rows.

I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_a (a_column json);
CREATE TABLE temp_b (b_column jsonb);
```

And kept inserting `{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz": 1}` into each of them.  The tables both increased in size from `8192` to `16384` and then `49152` at the same rate.

```
SELECT pg_table_size('temp_a'); SELECT pg_table_size('temp_b');
```